# Quantmod add indicators and save as csv (no chart)

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm very new to R and Quantmod.

Is it possible to add an indicator like MACD and save the timeseries as csv?

Displaying the chart is very easy:

```
getSymbols("AAPL",src="yahoo") 
barChart(AAPL)
addMACD()
```

But I want to add the indicators to the timeseries (save it as csv) and don't want to display it :)

Thanks!

How to do I tell the moving average to use the close-column?
e <- cbind( AAPL, SMA( AAPL, n=50) )

and how do I add additional columns to csv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `cbind` to add the signal.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL",src="yahoo")
d <- cbind( AAPL, MACD( AAPL ) )
write.csv(
  data.frame( date=index(d), coredata(d) ),
  row.names=FALSE,
  file="tmp.csv"
)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll check that at home

Comment: +1, though I would suggest using `write.zoo` instead of `write.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(quantmod)
foo=getSymbols("AAPL",src="yahoo") 
# tip: use ?barChart to see usage. The option plot=FALSE turns off plotting
x=barChart(foo,plot=FALSE)
# Look up ?MACD for a reference.
# x is a S4 object (https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4) 
ts_data=data.frame(cbind(x@xdata),MACD(x@xdata))
# ?write.csv is a function that will write this data frame to your current directory
write.csv(ts_data,file="my_data.csv")
```